# Magento 2: PHP Parse error when moved to production

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' Magento 2 Production mode

**[UPDATE]**

The reason I had this issue is that I had enabled the **Minify** Html from **Template Settings** in **Developer Configuration**.

Comment: can you send screenshot

Comment: I think it is a syntex error. Please check again.